# Get the output of a code on a remote machine in a browser

Tags: python, browser

I never did this before so I am sorry if my question is not very clear (I am not sure what the name of each step is). I have a code which is supposed to give me an interactive interface in a browser (similar to jupyter notebook I guess). After I run the code (I am using a remote machine, not my personal computer) one of the messages is: `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/` When I try to enter that in my browser I am getting a `This site can’t be reached` error. Also the terminal window used to run this code isn't active anymore (it is similar to when I run a jupyter notebook). What should I do to get access to that interactive windows created? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`http://127.0.0.1` is called loopback ip and is equivalent to `localhost`.
The remote machine is hosting the program on localhost, i.e., you cannot access it from other machine unless you host it on the machine's public ip.

Easiest way to do that is to host on `0.0.0.0:5000`. where 5000 is just a port and can be almost anything. Now that would probably print `Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/` but you need to access it with the machine's public ip.